# Reading xml tag by tag C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am reading tags of an XML file in c#,the code I have reads to the end of the file,but I want to read it tag by tag.In fact,I want to have a List in which every tag is saved.
Here is my xml:

```
<XML>
<Groups>
 <Group Name="Group1" ID="D7EBC5D6-0E6D-499E-B528-34BE14382755">
    <Item ID="9A4FA56F-EAA0-49AF-B7F0-8CA09EA39167"/>
    <Item ID="351FEF76-B826-426F-88C4-DBAAA60F886B"/>
    <Item ID="96A4CBFC-04CD-4D27-ADE6-585C05E4DBC9"/>
    <Item ID="D8876943-5861-4D62-9249-C5FEF88219FA"/>
</Group>
<Group Name="Group2" ID="CC012258-14AC-44E9-BA0F-78AE7C569FCB">
    <Item ID="9A4FA56F-EAA0-49AF-B7F0-8CA09EA39167"/>
    <Item ID="351FEF76-B826-426F-88C4-DBAAA60F886B"/>
</Group>
</Groups>
 <Items>
<Item>
    <GUID>9A4FA56F-EAA0-49AF-B7F0-8CA09EA39167</GUID>
    <Type>button</Type>
    <Title>Save</Title>
    <Value>submit</Value>
    <Name>btnsave</Name>
    <MaxLen>5</MaxLen>
</Item>    
<Item>
    <GUID>351FEF76-B826-426F-88C4-DBAAA60F886B</GUID>
    <Type>text</Type>
    <Title>Name:</Title>
    <Name>txtname</Name>
    <Value>Name</Value>
    <MaxLen>2</MaxLen>
</Item>
</Items>
</XML>
```

And my C# code:

```
    public Guid GroupsGuid;
    public Guid ItemsGuid;
    List<Guid> ItemsIndex = new List<Guid>();
    public string Datastring;        

    public override void LoadFromXML(string XMLFileAddress)
    {
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(XMLFileAddress);                      
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.Name)
            {
                case "Groups":
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                            break;
                        switch (reader.Name)
                        {
                            case "Group":
                                GroupsGuid=Guid.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("ID"));
                                Datastring += "<" + reader.Name + " name = " + reader.GetAttribute("Name") + " ID = " + GroupsGuid + "/>";
                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                                        break;
                                    switch (reader.Name)
                                    {
                                        case "Item":
                                            ItemsGuid = Guid.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("ID"));
                                            Datastring += "<" + reader.Name + " ID = " + reader.GetAttribute("ID") + "/>";                                                
                                            ItemsIndex.Add(GroupsGuid);
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to see the tags as on object in my program.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may helps:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(your file);
var result = doc.Descendants().ToList();
```

**EDIT:** To get the result (based on your comment) try this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(your file);

var groupItems = doc.Descendants("Group")
                    .SelectMany(i => i.Elements("Item"))
                    .Attributes("ID")
                    .Select(j => (string)j)
                    .ToList();

var nodes =       doc.Descendants("Items")
                     .Elements("Item")
                     .Where(i => groupItems.Contains((string)i.Element("GUID")))
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks but it is a bit more complicated,my problem is the fact that I need to read every "Item" in "Items" tag whose "GUID" is the same as the "Item" tag in Group tag.

Comment: So your problem is completely different

Comment: You might want to explain your real problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
         XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.Load(path);// write xml path

        XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ID");


        for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
        {
            string ID = elemList[i].Attributes["ID"].Value;

           listBox1.Items.Add(ID);


        }
```